# Want to capture load details for a specific load wise (not day wise)

Tags: sql-server

On a high level

Data is getting loaded to the table `TBL_PERM` everyday multiple times.

I want to capture load details for a specific load (not day-wise)

This query gives me a day-wise load

```
SELECT * INTO #TBL_TEMP
     FROM TBL_PERM
     WHERE RUNID = @RUN_ID;   --@RUN_ID - yyyymmdd(sysdate)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  #TBL_TEMP;
```

Why not directly from TBL_PERM? Because this will have records for the all days, but I want to capture load wise.

Suppose if we run the same file (having different data) on the same day, then how to capture for that specific load in temp table `#TBL_TEMP`?

Comment: Same file, different data, same day... won't these runs be represented by two different values of `RUNID`? If so, then I don't understand the problem. If not, then you need to show us some sample data and how we would tell these two runs apart.

Comment: As i read this, "capture load details for a specific load" means you want to capture information about a specific set of actions which implies you do that AT THE TIME those actions execute. After that process is completed, there is no way to get such information if you have no way of associating rows to "specific load".